# Why would a dimmer start buzzing when some lights are broken?

Tags: dimmer-switch

I have a dimmer that controls a 3-light fixture (filled with 35W halogen incandescents).

When the second light went dark (I procrastinated with replacing the first) the last one starts flickering, especially when dimmed a bit, and the dimmer starts buzzing (louder than normal). Is this normal?

Then a few weeks later the final light broke; coincidence or effect of the prolonged flickering?

Answer (score 2):

Dimmers have a minimum rating (as well as a maximum rating) and it is possible that one 35W fitting might not have been sufficient to reach the minimum.

The final lamp breaking might have been a result of the flickering.  Flickering incandescents are not good as it is like they are being turn on and off repeatedly and each time an incandescent lamp is switched on there is an extra rush of current as the filament is not at it's running temperature and therefore has a lower resistance and as a result each time you switch one on it dies a little.  A flickering light is being "switched on" lots of times and dying a little each time.